# Using Lambda functions with two different dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, lambda

I'm trying to use a lambda function to count the number of ocurrences of dataframe A values in dataframe B.

For example:
df_a:

```
col_a
a
b
c
d
h
```

df_b:

```
col_b
d
d
f
q
a
a
a
p
m
c
```

The way I thought to solve this was with something like this:

```
df_a["count"] = df_b.apply(lambda x: len(x[x.col_b == <item_in_df_a>]))
```

But I'm not having much success with this. How can I achieve the counting using lambda function?
I'm not quite sure that the `lambda` expression above is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin) to create a mask of matching elements then use [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-size) to count the ocurrences.

```
>>> mask = df_b['col_b'].isin(df_a['col_a'])
>>> df_b[mask].groupby('col_b').size().reset_index(name='count')

  col_b  count
0     a      3
1     c      1
2     d      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a join:

```
df_a.set_index('col_a').join(pd.DataFrame(df_b.groupby('col_b').size())).fillna(0)


       0
col_a   
a     3.0
b     0.0
c     1.0
d     2.0
h     0.0
```